# From semi-categories to categories via pro-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

While working in an area not generally associated directly with category theory, I was using the Grothendieck construction of pro- and ind- categories to show how various important classes of spaces arise in this context from certain seed categories, leading to a unified approach to the latter.  In the course of these investigations, I noticed the following phenomenon—in certain cases where the „seed category“ is actually only a semi-category, the resulting pro- or ind- semi-category, turned out to be, in fact, a category.  Hence my question: has this fact been observed before and is there a general condition on a semi-category (in the context of abstract category theory) which assures that this phenomenon occurs?

Comment: What do you mean by semi-category? A category without identity morphisms?\

Comment: Yes—I thought that this was standard terminology.  Though I would say „dropping the condition on the existence of identity morphisms“ (a category is a semi-category, after all).